# Table joins in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, laravel

### Database Structure

***users***

```
id | name
---+---------
 1 | OP
 2 | noob
```

***items***

```
id | name | user_id
---+------+--------
 1 | car  | 1
 2 | bus  | 2
 3 | box  | 1
```

***comments***

```
id | user_id | item_id | comment
---+---------+---------+---------------
 1 | 1       | 3       | this is a box.
```

### App

**app/routes.php**

```
View::share('top_comments', User::join('comments', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
                                  ->take(3)
                                  ->get()
);
```

**app/views/test.php**

```
@foreach ($top_comments as $comment)
    username: {{ $comment->name }}<br />
    comment: {{ $comment->comment }}<br />
    item id: {{ $comment->item_id }}
@endforeach
```

**current output**

```
username: OP
comment: this is a box
item id: 3
```

**desired output**

```
username: OP
comment: this is a box
item id: 3
item name: box
```

---

I want to be able to adjust my `top_comments` query to include `items.name`. Currently `{{ $comment->name }}` returns the user's name. I think having the same field name is causing a conflict... suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this:

```
User::join('comments', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
    ->join('items', 'users.id', '=', 'items.user_id')
    ->get(array('users.*', 'comments.*', 'items.user_id', 'items.name as itemname'));
```

In the `view`:

```
@foreach ($top_comments as $comment)
    ...
    item name: {{ $comment->itemname }}
@endforeach
```